# Update useEffect returned function in a rerender without calling it

Tags: reactjs

In the following code the returned function inside useEffect, is called when the component unmounts.

```
function MyComponent() {
    const [variable, setVariable] = useState(1)
    
    useEffect(() => {
      return () => console.log(variable);
    }, []);
    setVariable(2);
}
```

But I want a thing different from the above code: I want that the definition of the returned function become updated when the variable value is changed, without calling it (except when it is time to unmount). What should I do?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should set `variable` as a dependency for `useEffect`:

```
function MyComponent() {
    const [variable, setVariable] = useState(1)
    
    useEffect(() => {
      return () => console.log(variable);
    }, [variable]);
    setVariable(2);
}
```

Therefore  `console.log` runs whenever `variable` changes.

Comment: I want that the returned function from useEffect be called just when the component unmounts. But putting the variable as dependency, causes the function to be called in every change of variable. (I have noted this, in the title but now, I also added it in the question body)

Comment: @MohammadGhiasi I Don't think to is a need to update. when this was unmounted, `console.log(variable)` shows an up-to-date value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
function MyComponent() {
    const [variable, setVariable] = useState(1)
    const [unmountingFunction, setUnmountingFunction] = useState(() => console.log(variable))

    //whenever you update value, this unmounting function will be updated too
    useEffect(() => {
      setUnmountingFunction(() => console.log("Your unmounting function is here"))
    }, [variable]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
      return unmountingFunction;
    }, []);
    setVariable(2);
}
```